# How can I count the different file types within a folder using linux terminal?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

Hey I'm star struck on how to count the different amounts of file types / extensions recursively in a folder. I also need to print them to a .txt file.

For example I have 10 txt's 20 .docx files mixed up in multiple folders.

Help me !

Answer (score 9):

```
find ./ -type f |awk -F . '{print $NF}' | sort | awk '{count[$1]++}END{for(j in count) print j,"("count[j]" occurences)"}'
```

Gets all filenames with `find`, then uses `awk` to get the extension, then uses `awk` again to count the occurences

Comment: Thanks so much life saver!

Answer (score 1):

Just with bash: version 4 required for this code

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar nullglob
declare -A exts

for f in * **/*; do
    [[ -f $f ]] || continue     # only count files
    filename=${f##*/}           # remove directories from pathname
    ext=${filename##*.}
    [[ $filename == $ext ]] && ext="no_extension"
    : ${exts[$ext]=0}           # initialize array element if unset
    (( exts[$ext]++ ))
done

for ext in "${!exts[@]}"; do
    echo "$ext ${exts[$ext]}"
done | sort -k2nr | column -t
```

Comment: This is spectacular.  Cleanly formatted.  Breaks out no extension on its own.  Sorts by frequency.  Well done.

Answer (score 0):

this one seems unsolved so far, so here is how far I got counting files and ordering them:

```
find . -type f | sed -n 's/..*\.//p' | sort -f | uniq -ic
```